# Removing 1000s of comments in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, comments, jd-gui

I installed JD-GUI to retrieve my code from a jar file. Everything works fine, except JD-GUI automatically adds annoying comments like this:

[image]

Any way I can remove them? I don't understand regex.

Comment: please try to include your code in the post as text if you still don't have enough reputation to attach an image.. since this question will become useless once the link broken..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CTRL+H`. Within "File Search" > "Search string", check "Regular expression" and use one of the regex given by the other answers.

Then use "Replace..." to replace them all with nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Using Eclipse:

Go to `Edit > Find/Replace...`
Use this regular expression in the **Find** box: `^/\* [0-9 ]{3} \*/`

- `^` match start of line.
- `/\*` match start of comment
- `[0-9 ]{3}` match exactly three digits/spaces
- `\*/` match end of comment

Make sure the **Replace** box is empty.
Make sure the **Regular expressions** checkbox is selected.
Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: Will the line number in the comments always be exactly 3 digits/spaces? `\d+`will match any number of digits.

Comment: @ahuth Some of the comments are of the form `/*     */`, and will not be matched by `\d+`. You could, however, use `[0-9 ]*` to match any number of digits and/or spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Use the utility [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) to search for a regex and replace with an empty string. [Here](https://gist.github.com/un33k/1162378#file-sed-cheatsheet-L91) is a gist that should get you started with using it.

Since you don't understand regex, I'll help you out with it: `/^\/\* \d+ \*\//gm` will find every comment block that starts at the beginning of a line and contains a line number.

Here's how it works:

- `/` is the start of the regex
- `^` matches the begnning of the line
- `\/\*` finds the opening `/*` of the comment
- (space) finds the space before the line number
- `\d+` finds any number of digits
- (space) finds the space after the line number
- `\*\/` finds the ending `*/` of the comment
- `/gm` ends the regex and flags this as a global, multiline search