# Source code has comments after decompile whith JD-GUI

Tags: java, decompiler, jd-gui

I have converted class files into source code by JD GUI Tool. I open the jar file using JD-GUI version 0.3.5, then open File folder and click "Save All Sources". There are comments in source code, e.g.:

```
/*     */
/*     */ @ManagedBean
/*  60   */ @SessionScoped
```

How can I remove those comments?

Comment: Look through the settings for JD, I think you can turn them off..

Comment: There are only 5 tabs in JD, [File, Edit, Navigate, Search, Help] and no 'Setting' among them. Should I use JD Project or JD Eclipse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing 1000s of comments in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967176/removing-1000s-of-comments-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the setting under `Help > Preferences` and **uncheck** `Display line numbers` as in image;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-decompiler-and-its) you can turn off in (Only works with JD Eclipse)

```
Window –> Preferences –> Java –> Decompiler
```

And uncheck `line numbers`

Like this:

[image]

These comments are the line number from the `.class` file.

Comment: Thanks, that's the Great post. :)